# Format text input with custom tagged entities into sklearn-crfsuite format

Tags: python, nlp, tagging

I have some custom data that should be used for entity recognition and I plan to use pythons sklearn-crfsuite for the same.
The data looks as below:

```
I   O
want    O
a   O
black   color
shoe    product
of  O
size    O
9   size
..
I   O
want    O
a   O
blue    color
shirt   product
of  O
brand   O
Arrow   brand
size    O
XL  size
..
I   O
want    O
a   O
white   color
khaki   product-subcategory
shirt   product
of  O
size    M
```

However I need to change the format to something like:

```
[('Melbourne', 'NP', 'B-LOC'),
 ('(', 'Fpa', 'O'),
 ('Australia', 'NP', 'B-LOC'),
 (')', 'Fpt', 'O'),
 (',', 'Fc', 'O'),
 ('25', 'Z', 'O'),
 ('may', 'NC', 'O'),
 ('(', 'Fpa', 'O'),
 ('EFE', 'NC', 'B-ORG'),
 (')', 'Fpt', 'O'),
 ('.', 'Fp', 'O')]
```

as required by the package's trainer. 
Can someone please help me regarding this.
What I have done is:

```
list_of_lists = []
with open('./trainData.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        inner_list = [elt.strip() for elt in line.split('..')]
        list_of_lists.append(inner_list)
```

But this is not achieving what I want and the output is:

list_of_lists
Out[25]:

```
[['I\tO'],
 ['want\tO'],
 ['a\tO'],
 ['black\tcolor'],
 ['shoe\tproduct'],
 ['of\tO'],
 ['size\tO'],
 ['9\tsize'],
 ['', ''],
 ['I\tO'],
 ['want\tO'],
 ['a\tO'],
 ['blue\tcolor'],
 ['shirt\tproduct'],
 ['of\tO'],
 ['brand\tO'],
 ['Arrow\tbrand'],
 ['size\tO'],
 ['XL\tsize']
```

Comment: The fields are separated by tabs (`\t`), not `".."`. So split on tabs, not `".."`. Note that the Melbourne example has tuples of length 3, while you are generating lists of length 2.

Comment: I think there are two levels of splitting that have to be done. One will be to split into individual sentences and then into words. So the first sentence will produce a list of words with the tags. And the corpus as a whole will be a list of such sentences.But the problem is that the word seperator and sentence separator are not the same.